# facebookconnectplugin cordova fb.api not returning any data

Tags: android, cordova, facebook-graph-api

I am using facebookconnectplugin https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin in my cordova android app. I am able to successfully connect, logout and getloginstatus but am not able to use Graphi API. When I Use the api, no data is returned and no error either. I am using Netbeans for development.

Example code given below:

```
function fbAPI() {
    console.log("fbAPI");

    var fbAPIResponse = function (userData) {
        console.log("fbAPI - " + JSON.stringify(userData));
    }
    facebookConnectPlugin.api("me/?fields=id,last_name", fbAPIResponse);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax of the graph api for phonegap is

```
    facebookConnectPlugin.api(String requestPath, Array permissions, Function success, Function failure)
```

This API allows for additional permission because, unlike login, the Graph API can accept multiple permissions.

```
    ["public_profile", "user_birthday"]
```

So your updated code should be

```
    facebookConnectPlugin.api("me/?fields=id,last_name",["public_profile"], fbAPIResponse);
```